# Android : How to control reloading of data in previous Activity when back button pressed

Tags: android, performance

I am Using TabGroupActivity for my project. In first tab, i moved from Activity A -> B . when i pressed back button in Activity B ,i moving back to 'A' and the data in Activity A is reloading again from server. I dont want to reload data again and again when back button pressed. When back button pressed simply it has to return 'A' with out reloading. How to do this... Any suggestion please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are implementing ActivityGroup Implementation of tab bar, which creates entire activity's view and set this view to window, so, by ActivityGroup it is not feasible to maintain back stack, and also Activity group is depricated, so see Fragments for solution, which can maintain, back stack individually.